# Java: practical use of PhantomReference?

Tags: java, phantom-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Have you ever used Phantom reference in any project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599069/have-you-ever-used-phantom-reference-in-any-project)

What are practical uses of PhantomReference? Since their 'get' always returns null, the objects they point to can't be accessed through them. So what's their use? Through subclassing maybe (similar to how WeakReference is subclassed in WeakHashMap)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599069/have-you-ever-used-phantom-reference-in-any-project

Comment: @Brian Roach and others, I wanted to see some code examples using PhantomReference, but didn't mention it in my question. My bad. If I modify the question appropriately, could you pl. consider reopening it?