# How to use PhantomReference as finalize() Replacement

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalizer, finalize, phantom-reference

Javadoc 8 for [PhantomReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html)
 states:

> Phantom references are most often used for scheduling **pre-mortem** cleanup actions in a more flexible way than is possible with the Java finalization mechanism.

So I tried creating a thread that is calling the `close()` method of a Test  Object that is eligible for garbage collection. The `run()` tries to get all Test Objects **pre-mortem**.

Actually the retrieved Test Objects are all `null`. The expected behavior is, that the Test Objects are retrieved and the `close`method is called.

No matter how many Test Objects you create there is not a single Test Object that could be caught **pre-mortem** (You have to increase the timeouts and call GC multiple times).

What am I doing wrong? Is this a Java Bug?

#### Runnable Test Code:

I tried to create a *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*, but it's still quite long. I use `java version "1.8.0_121"` 32-bit on Windows 7 64-bit.

```
public class TestPhantomReference {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Create AutoClose Thread and start it
        AutoCloseThread thread = new AutoCloseThread();
        thread.start();

        // Add 10 Test Objects to the AutoClose Thread
        // Test Objects are directly eligible for GC
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            thread.addObject(new Test());
        }

        // Sleep 1 Second, run GC, sleep 1 Second, interrupt AutoCLose Thread
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("System.gc()");
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        thread.interrupt();
    }

    public static class Test {
        public void close() {
            System.out.println("close()");
        }
    }

    public static class AutoCloseThread extends Thread {
        private ReferenceQueue<Test> mReferenceQueue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
        private Stack<PhantomReference<Test>> mPhantomStack = new Stack<>();

        public void addObject(Test pTest) {
            // Create PhantomReference for Test Object with Reference Queue, add Reference to Stack
            mPhantomStack.push(new PhantomReference<Test>(pTest, mReferenceQueue));
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    // Get PhantomReference from ReferenceQueue and get the Test Object inside
                    Test testObj = mReferenceQueue.remove().get();
                    if (null != testObj) {
                        System.out.println("Test Obj call close()");
                        testObj.close();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Test Obj is null");
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Expected Output:

```
System.gc()
Test Obj call close()
close()
Test Obj call close()
close()
Thread Interrupted
```

#### Actual Output:

```
System.gc()
Test Obj is null
Test Obj is null
Thread Interrupted
```

Comment: `Test testObj = mReferenceQueue.remove().get();` will always be null . Change that block of code to `mReferenceQueue.remove().close()` and it'll work. `queue.remove()` will block correctly and always return you an object. There's no need to test for `null`.

Comment: Hello @Pacerier . `mReferenceQueue.remove()` will return a `Reference<? extends Test>` Object and not the `Test` Object, so I can't call `mReferenceQueue.remove().close()`. Maybe you can provide more details.

Answer (score 8):

This is by design. Unlike `finalize()`, which makes an object reachable again, objects referable by a `Reference` object only can not be made reachable again. So when you are going to manage a resource through it, you have to store the necessary information into another object. It’s not unusual, to use the `Reference` object itself for it.

Consider the following modifications to your test program:

```
public class TestPhantomReference {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // create two Test Objects without closing them
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            new Test(i);
        }
        // create two Test Objects with proper resource management
        try(Test t2=new Test(2); Test t3=new Test(3)) {
            System.out.println("using Test 2 and 3");
        }

        // Sleep 1 Second, run GC, sleep 1 Second
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("System.gc()");
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    static class TestResource extends PhantomReference<Test> {
        private int id;
        private TestResource(int id, Test referent, ReferenceQueue<Test> queue) {
            super(referent, queue);
            this.id = id;
        }
        private void close() {
            System.out.println("closed "+id);
        }
    }    
    public static class Test implements AutoCloseable {
        static AutoCloseThread thread = new AutoCloseThread();
        static { thread.start(); }
        private final TestResource resource;
        Test(int id) {
            resource = thread.addObject(this, id);
        }
        public void close() {
            resource.close();
            thread.remove(resource);
        }
    }

    public static class AutoCloseThread extends Thread {
        private ReferenceQueue<Test> mReferenceQueue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
        private Set<TestResource> mPhantomStack = new HashSet<>();

        public AutoCloseThread() {
            setDaemon(true);
        }
        TestResource addObject(Test pTest, int id) {
            final TestResource rs = new TestResource(id, pTest, mReferenceQueue);
            mPhantomStack.add(rs);
            return rs;
        }
        void remove(TestResource rs) {
            mPhantomStack.remove(rs);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    TestResource rs = (TestResource)mReferenceQueue.remove();
                    System.out.println(rs.id+" not properly closed, doing it now");
                    mPhantomStack.remove(rs);
                    rs.close();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which will print:

```
using Test 2 and 3
closed 3
closed 2
System.gc()
0 not properly closed, doing it now
closed 0
1 not properly closed, doing it now
closed 1
```

showing how using the correct idiom ensures that resources are closed timely and, unlike `finalize()`, the object can opt out the post-mortem cleanup which makes using the correct idiom even more efficient, as in that case, no additional GC cycle is needed to reclaim the object after finalization.

Comment: Could you please explain why the test objects in the try-with-resources block won't be added to the reference queue? Aren't they finalized because of any special relationship between autocloseable and the gc I do not know about?

Comment: @user35934 mind [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#package.description): “*The relationship between a registered reference object and its queue is one-sided. That is, a queue does not keep track of the references that are registered with it. If a registered reference becomes unreachable itself, then it will never be enqueued.*” That’s why this solution keeps track with the `Set<TestResource> mPhantomStack`. The `close()` method removes the resource, making it unreachable, thus allowing it to get collected.

Comment: Invoking `clear​()` on the reference would also have the effect of preventing enqueuing, but it has to be removed from the global set anyway.  —  Note that the logic of this solution is the same as implemented in [the `Cleaner` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html), which was introduced with Java 9, a few months after this answer. In that API, your `close()` method would invoke [`Cleanable.clean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.Cleanable.html#clean--) to perform the cleanup action and unregister it.

Comment: _"The close() method removes the resource, making it unreachable, thus allowing it to get collected."_ That was my thought, but if I comment out `thread.remove(resource);` in the `close()`-method the objects with id 2 and 3 are still not enqueued, even though both references are still held in the stack. You can tryit for yourself.

Comment: @user35934 that’s the unreliability of garbage collection. In this specific case, there are dangling references in the stack frame at the point, `System.gc()` is called. You have two options, you can 1) run the example with `-Xcomp` or 2) insert, e.g. `long dummy = 42;` right before the `System.gc();` line. In both cases, it will show that `thread.remove(resource);` makes a difference. In real life applications, you don’t have such issues.

Comment: Interesting, didn't no dangling references were possible in java and that you can work around it with this special command line option. Many thanks for your feedback, learned a lot.

Comment: @user35934 the point to understand is, that the scope of local variables is a compile-time thing. In the bytecode, there are only write and read instructions addressing indices in the stack frame. So there could be dangling references, but it can also work the other way round; in optimized executions, variables might be still “in scope”, but the referenced object gets collected, because its not used afterwards. `-Xcomp` just disables the interpreter and the JIT compiler emits code dropping the references right after the last use. As said, in real life applications, this normally doesn’t matter

Answer (score 5):

`get()` method on phantom references always return null.

At the moment phantom reference is enqueued object it was referencing is already collected by GC. You need to store data required to clean up in separate object (e.g. you can subclass `PhantomReference`).

[Here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2016/03/finalizers-and-references-in-java.html) you can find example code and more elaborate description about using `PhantomReference`s.

Unlike finalizer, phantom reference cannot resurrect unreachable object. This is its main advantage, though cost is more complicated supporting code.